# Java enum with multiple value types

Tags: java, enums

Basically what I've done is write an enum for States, and I want to not only be able to access them just as states but also access their abbreviation and whether or not they were an original colony.

```
public enum States {
        ...
        MASSACHUSETTS("Massachusetts",  "MA",   true),
        MICHIGAN("Michigan",            "MI",   false),
            ...; //so on and so forth for all fifty states

        private final Object[] values;

        States(Object... vals) {
            values = vals;
        }

        public String FULL() {
            return (String) values[0];
        }

        public String ABBR() {
            return (String) values[1];
        }

        public boolean ORIGINAL_COLONY(){
            return (boolean) values[2];
        }
    }
```

This seems to work as I'd expect it to. I can

```
System.out.println(States.ALABAMA);                  // Prints "ALABAMA"
System.out.println(States.ALABAMA.FULL());           // Prints "Alabama"
System.out.println(States.ALABAMA.ABBR());           // Prints "AL"
System.out.println(States.ALABAMA.ORIGINAL_COLONY());// Prints "false"
```

For this particular scenario involving enums, is this the best way to do this or is there a better way to setup and format this enum? Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: The methods shouldn't be in all caps.

Comment: Not even for enums? Normally I use camel case, but I thought when referencing something static that never gets changed it should be all caps much like the enum itself would be.

Comment: It's also better if you actually had fields like `name`, `abbreviation`, `isOriginalColony` and had a constructor taking `(String, String, boolean)`. That way, it's more readable, and also helps prevent someone adding in another state with the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: Also more efficient, fwiw.

Comment: @SonofLysander Methods themselves should always be camel case. I've only never seen all caps for enums and constants (like for example, `Math.PI`).

Comment: Bamf. Okay, changed everything as suggested so far by you everyone. Anything else?

Comment: Other than what Sotirios and I mentioned, I don't see anything particularly wrong, though some people might disagree with the constructor visibility. The states themselves should probably be listed in alphabetical order (though it looks like you might be doing that already :) ), and of course, there shouldn't be any surprises in the methods.

Comment: (I've also seen all caps for `static final` references that aren't compile-time constants, though I personally don't like that. For instance, `public static final FOO = System.getProperty("foo")`)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

First, the enum methods shouldn't be in all caps. They are methods just like other methods, with the same naming convention.

Second, what you are doing is not the best possible way to set up your enum. Instead of using an array of values for the values, you should use separate variables for each value. You can then implement the constructor like you would any other class.

Here's how you should do it with all the suggestions above:

```
public enum States {
    ...
    MASSACHUSETTS("Massachusetts",  "MA",   true),
    MICHIGAN     ("Michigan",       "MI",   false),
    ...; // all 50 of those

    private final String full;
    private final String abbr;
    private final boolean originalColony;

    private States(String full, String abbr, boolean originalColony) {
        this.full = full;
        this.abbr = abbr;
        this.originalColony = originalColony;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return full;
    }

    public String getAbbreviatedName() {
        return abbr;
    }

    public boolean isOriginalColony(){
        return originalColony;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marcin why shouldn't that be private?

Comment: enum constructors are implicitly private

Comment: How to call the method. What would States.getAbbreviatedName() will print in sysout?

Comment: we can use `Status.valueOf("MASSACHUSETTS").getAbbreviatedName();`, `Status.valueOf("MASSACHUSETTS").isOriginalColony();`, etc

Comment: How to have a default value in this case in-case enum does not match?

Comment: This does not work in C# right ?

Answer (score -1):

**This is a filtered value from list**

```
List<String> valueList= Stream.of(States.values())
               .filter(m->m.ORIGINAL_COLONY()==true)
                .map(m->m.ABBR())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    enter code here



public enum States {
    MASSACHUSETTS("Massachusetts",  "MA",   true),
    CHICAGO("Chicago",  "MA",   true),
    TROUT("trout",  "MA",   true),
    MICHIGAN("Michigan",            "MI",   false);
    private final Object[] values;

    States(Object... vals) {
        values = vals;
    }

    public String FULL() {
        return (String) values[0];
    }

    public String ABBR() {
        return (String) values[1];
    }




    public boolean ORIGINAL_COLONY(){
        return (boolean) values[2];
    }
}
```