# Should the HashMap<String,String> be refactored to Enum?

Tags: java, enumeration

I have a map which represents the key name (group id prefix) mapping between prefixName and the sequence name of each sequence defined in the database. For example, if the groupId is "GRP-MMM-PNL", I should get the corresponding sequence name "mmm_panel_group_id" of that group. My question is should I use Enum instead of defining this HashMap.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum SequenceName {

    mmm_panel_group_id("GRP-MMM-PNL-"),
    mmm_service_group_id("GRP-MMM-SRV-"),
    
    cms_panel_group_id("GRP-CMS-PNL-"),
    cms_service_group_id("GRP-CMS-SRV-"),

    smm_panel_group_id("GRP-SMM-PNL-"),
    smm_service_group_id("GRP-SMM-SRV-");
    
    @Getter
    private String groupPrefix;
}

private static HashMap<String, String> getPrefixSequenceNameMap() {

        HashMap<String, String> prefixSequenceNameMap = new HashMap<>();
        prefixSequenceNameMap.put("GRP-MMM-PNL-", "mmm_panel_group_id");
        prefixSequenceNameMap.put("GRP-MMM-SRV-", "mmm_service_group_id");

        prefixSequenceNameMap.put("GRP-CMS-PNL-", "cms_panel_group_id");
        prefixSequenceNameMap.put("GRP-CMS-SRV-", "cms_service_group_id");

        prefixSequenceNameMap.put("GRP-SMM-PNL-", "smm_panel_group_id");
        prefixSequenceNameMap.put("GRP-SMM-SRV-", "smm_service_group_id");

        return prefixSequenceNameMap;
    }
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600768

Comment: Why are you asking? What makes you wonder specifically about it being an Enum instead of a Hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "should". It depends on what you want.

- If the values are known at compile-time and they do not change, an enum might be better. You can still use a Map though.
- If the values are only known at run-time or they change while the program is running, use a Map.